# Hibernate inserts null for date field in table whose default value is set to sysdate in table

Tags: hibernate

I'm creating web application. I'm using Spring and hibernate. When doing the below,

```
userprofile.setFirstName(firstname);
        userprofile.setLastName(lastname);
        userprofile.setDob(bday);
        userprofile.setPhoneNumber(telephone);
        userprofile.setEmailId(email);
        userprofile.setPassword(password);
//      userprofile.setCreatedDate(sysdate);
        session.save(userprofile);
        t.commit();
```

Hibernate is generating the below insert query

```
Hibernate: insert into USER_PROFILE (CREATED_DATE, DATE_OF_BIRTH, EMAIL_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PASSWORD, PHONE_NUMBER, PROFILE_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

which is inserting null value in my created_date field. I've made that created_date field's default value as sysdate.
Please help me to sort out this.

Comment: Post your userprofile class

Answer (score 1):

I got it resolved..In pojo class, the following insertable=false should be added. This will avoid insertion of null and default value set in table will be inserted instead.

```
@Column(name = "CREATED_DATE", insertable=false)
    private Date createdDate;
```